# python Mysterious delay in data stream

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, raspberry-pi, rpc

i'm streaming data from the game ksp using a plugin called KRPC and a python script here is the documentation for krpc: https://krpc.github.io/krpc/
there never use to be a delay between the data my program was displaying and the data on the game end until i multi-threaded my program now i'm getting up to a  second delay. multi-threading my python program is important because it seemed to have stopped the script from hanging or crashing. i can't figure out what is causing the delay. my python script is running on a raspberry pi so i'm trying to keep the CPU usage low

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import Adafruit_Nokia_LCD as LCD
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import krpc
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
from UUGear import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
try:

    device = UUGearDevice('UUGear-Arduino-5343-9628')
    if not device.isValid():
        exit()

    KEYPAD = [
            [1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            ["*",0,"#"]
    ]

    ROW_PINS = [4,5,12,16] # BCM numbering
    COL_PINS = [26,6,13] # BCM numbering
    global pressedkey
    pressedkey = '0'
    factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

    # Try factory.create_4_by_3_keypad
    # and factory.create_4_by_4_keypad for reasonable defaults
    keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)

    def procKey(key):
        print(key)
        global pressedkey
        pressedkey = str(key)

    # printKey will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
    keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(procKey)


    # Raspberry Pi hardware SPI config:
    DC = 23
    RST = 24
    SPI_PORT = 0
    SPI_DEVICE = 0


    # Hardware SPI usage:
    disp = LCD.PCD8544(DC, RST, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=4000000))

    # Software SPI usage (defaults to bit-bang SPI interface):
    #disp = LCD.PCD8544(DC, RST, SCLK, DIN, CS)

    # Initialize library.
    disp.begin(contrast=60)
    disp.clear()
    disp.display()

    image = Image.new('1', (LCD.LCDWIDTH, LCD.LCDHEIGHT))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)


    # Load default font.
    font = ImageFont.load_default()
    draw.rectangle((0,0,83,47), outline=255, fill=255)
    draw.text((15,0), 'Loading...', font=font)
    disp.image(image)
    disp.display()


    conn = krpc.connect(name='rpi', address='192.168.0.10', rpc_port=50000, stream_port=50001)
    vessel = conn.space_center.active_vessel

    draw.rectangle((0,0,83,47), outline=255, fill=255)
    draw.text((0,0), '--FLIGHT SYS--', font=font)
    draw.text((3,10), '1 - Surface', font=font)
    draw.text((3,20), '2 - Orbit', font=font)
    disp.image(image)
    disp.display()



    device.setPinModeAsInput(9)
    device.setPinModeAsInput(2)
    device.setPinModeAsInput(3)
    device.setPinModeAsInput(4)
    device.setPinModeAsOutput(12)
    vessel.control.sas = False
    prev_input_stage = 0
    prev_input_parachute = 0
    input_stage = '0'
    input_parachute = '0'
    def screen():
        global apoapsis
        global periapsis
        global altitude
        global pressedkey
        global draw
        global font
        global disp
        global conn
        global vessel
        ut = conn.add_stream(getattr, conn.space_center, 'ut')
        altitude = conn.add_stream(getattr, vessel.flight(), 'mean_altitude')
        apoapsis = conn.add_stream(getattr, vessel.orbit, 'apoapsis_altitude')
        periapsis = conn.add_stream(getattr, vessel.orbit, 'periapsis_altitude')
        while True:
            print 'AP:', apoapsis()
            print 'Pe:', periapsis()
            print 'Alt:', altitude()
            #for parachute in vessel.parts.parachutes:
            #   print parachute.state
            if pressedkey == '2':
                draw.rectangle((0,0,83,47), outline=255, fill=255)
                if abs(apoapsis()) < 1000:
                    draw.text((0,0), 'Ap:' + str(round(apoapsis(), 2)) + 'M', font=font)
                else:
                    draw.text((0,0), 'Ap:' + str(round(apoapsis()/1000, 2)) + 'KM', font=font)

                if abs(periapsis()) < 1000:
                    draw.text((0,10), 'Pe:' + str(round(periapsis(), 2)) + 'M', font=font)
                else:
                    draw.text((0,10), 'Pe:' + str(round(periapsis()/1000, 2)) + 'KM', font=font)

            if pressedkey == '1':
                draw.rectangle((0,0,83,47), outline=255, fill=255)
                if abs(altitude()) < 1000:
                    draw.text((0,0), 'Alt:' + str(round(altitude(), 2)) + 'M', font=font)
                else:
                    draw.text((0,0), 'Alt:' + str(round(altitude()/1000, 2)) + 'KM', font=font)
            if pressedkey == '#':
                draw.rectangle((0,0,83,47), outline=255, fill=255)
                draw.text((0,0), '--FLIGHT SYS--', font=font)
                draw.text((3,10), '1 - Surface', font=font)
                draw.text((3,20), '2 - Orbit', font=font)

            disp.image(image)
            disp.display()

    def hardware():
        global input_stage
        global prev_input_stage
        global vessel
        global device
        global input_parachute
        global prev_input_parachute
        while True:
            input_stage = not device.getPinStatus(9)
            if ((not prev_input_stage) and input_stage):
                vessel.control.activate_next_stage()
                print("stage")
                print 'Pin 9 status=', device.getPinStatus(9)
            prev_input_stage = input_stage

            input_parachute = not device.getPinStatus(2)
            if ((not prev_input_parachute) and input_parachute):
                for parachute in vessel.parts.parachutes:
                    parachute.deploy()
                print("Parachute")
                print 'Pin 2 status=', device.getPinStatus(2)
            #print(device.analogRead(3))
            prev_input_parachute = input_parachute
            vessel.control.sas = not device.getPinStatus(4)

            if vessel.control.sas == True:
                device.setPinHigh(12)
            else:
                device.setPinLow(12)

            for engines in vessel.parts.engines:
                if engines.gimballed == True:
                    engines.gimbal_locked = bool(device.getPinStatus(3))
            time.sleep(0.2)
    t1 = Thread(target = screen)
    t2 = Thread(target = hardware)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
except:
    print 'Interrupted'
    print 'Cleaning up'
    GPIO.cleanup()  
    device.detach()
    device.stopDaemon()
    keypad.cleanup()
```

Comment: Linux threads are going to be unpredictable for real-time use. Threads don't reduce the CPU load - they only allow the CPU to do other tasks while the thread is running.